# Store Camera Preview After Every 1 Second Android

Tags: java, android, android-camera, frame-rate

I want to store the Camera Preview after every second. Problem is the frame rate cannot go below 20-24.

Currently it stores around 170 images in 5 sec. 
`onPreviewFrame` is being called **ULTRA** frequently which i want to slow down to 1 preview per second. I used `Thread.sleep()` but i guess its not a nice of doing it. I want to store 1 image in 1 sec. Any leads on this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you just ignore 19 of the 20 frames per second in your callback?

Comment: yea i did that by calling the store function after a multiple of 20. its solved

Comment: @gursahib.singh.sahni How you did this. I also want to capture preview frame after 500ms, that means i want to take only 1 preview frame per 500 milliseconds.

Comment: @sam_k , i guess FPS is device dependent. You may skip capturing the preview by calling the capture method after the desired interval.

Comment: @gursahib.singh.sahni Can you please give me idea or answer on my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564273/how-to-get-camera-preview-frame-after-every-500ms

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setPreviewCallback go for 
**setOneShotPreviewCallback**: This callback gives you only one frame and the callback will get cleared. You can keep calling this at every one second interval or when you are done with storing previous frame.